# asp.net viewstate character encoding special characters

Tags: asp.net, character-encoding, viewstate

I'm trying to see if anyone else has ran into this and if there is a possible solution.
When a user enters a special character (say a copyright symbol) it shows correctly, however after I save the data to viewstate a ? appears.

Has anyone else ran into this and how can I have the data save the symbol.
I know the preferred method is to have them encode, but they're graphic designers and don't get it.
Also the editor I'm using (obout) inserts the symbol not encoded, so my hands are tied there as well.

Comment: What do you mean by "a ? appears?"  Where does the question mark appear, after doing what?

Comment: don't think is related to viewstate. it should be related to page or database encoding. Debug your code before saving to db and when you load from it.

Comment: this is a multi-part process to save information and the data is saved in viewstate until the final step. so as example: on the first step, there is a textbox for "name". After information is entered and "next button" is clicked info is saved to viewstate. When I access viewstate the special character is replaced with a ?.

Comment: Claudio, I have nvarchar in database. I can insert the symbol directly there. On pageload (loaded into viewstate) the ? appears as well. I've double checked everything in the database and it's good. What do you mean page encoding?

Comment: Your issue have nothing to do with viewstate. Can you show the code and the text that have the issue ?

Comment: As @ClaudioRedi said, this is very likely a page encoding problem.  Check that your page is being served up as UTF-8 and that the character set in the head, if set, is set to UTF-8 as well.  Also, it may be worth HtmlEncode()ing the values that come out of the database or viewstate, so that they appear correctly on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging through everything one of the stored procedures was referencing a varchar not nvarchar so that was the issue.

A nvarchar column can store any Unicode data. A varchar column is restricted to an 8-bit codepage.